# How to get checkbox checked from database array using Laravel and Ajax

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, laravel, checkbox

I'm trying to get data from database to checkboxes as checked. The checkbox data in database are as array that have been inserted with json and they are dynamic data based on insert function.

My tasks table:

```
id |employee_id | startDate  | endDate   | ...
---|------------|------------|-----------|--------
1  |["1","2"]   | .......... | ..........| ....
```

My TasksController.php

```
function fetchdata(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $task = Task::find($id);
        $output = array(
            'employee_id'    =>  $task->employee_id,
            'name'    =>  $task->name,
            'description'    =>  $task->description,
            'startDate'    =>  $task->startDate,
            'endDate'    =>  $task->endDate,
            'percentage'    =>  $task->percentage       

        );
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    public function getEmployeesList()
    {

        $employeesList = Employee::all();


        return view('adminlte::tasks', ['employeesList' => $employeesList]);


    }
```

My tasks.blade.php

```
 @foreach($employeesList as $emplist)
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" id="employee_id" name="employee_id[]" class="chck" value="{{$emplist->id}}" >{{ $emplist->name }}</label>    
 @endforeach
```

My Ajax function inside blade:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#form_output').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('tasks.fetchdata')}}",
            method: 'get',
            data: {id:id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#id').val(data.id);
                $('#employee_id').val(data.employee_id);
                $('#name').val(data.name);
                .......................
                ..................
            }
        })
    });
```

So, how can I retrieve data from database to checkboxes as checked, because for now I'm getting null "employee_id" value when I try to update a record.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since you're encoding the data on the server side, you must decode it in the client side like :

```
...
success:function(data)
{
    console.log( data );
    data = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#id').val(data.id);
    $('#employee_id').val(data.employee_id);
    $('#name').val(data.name);
    ...

}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. I tried also with data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)), not getting error but nothing happened with checkboxes.

Comment: change `echo json_encode($output);` to `return json_encode($output);` then check my updated answer with `console.log( data );` try it and show us the output.

Comment: Console Log: ```{employee_id: "["1","2"]", name: "test", description: "test", startDate: "2019/03/25 15:44", endDate: "2019/03/26 15:44", …}```  and the the same error too.

Comment: The problem then comes from the PHP side array so try `dd( json_encode($output) );` and edit your question by adding the full output.

Comment: ```dd( json_encode($output) );``` is not working, I'm not getting any thing

Comment: You need to check the network tab to see the returned result

Comment: Yes I checked and this is the response: ```"{"employee_id":"[\"1\",\"2\"]","name":"test","description":"test","startDate":"2019\/03\/25 15:44","endDate":"2019\/03\/26 15:44","percentage":10}"```

Comment: Ok, remove the dd and the console.log() returning back to the original code, then comment `'employee_id'    =>  $task->employee_id,` line and rechek.

Comment: I removed dd and console.log(). So, I returned back ```return json_encode($output)``` and the code ```data = JSON.parse(data);``` in blade.
After checking, I'm getting same error: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: HAve you commented this line `'employee_id' => $task->employee_id,` in your controller?

Comment: Yes, I have commented the line.